# Bitcoin-core 0.15.1 gettransaction showing wrong fee for some transactions

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

What makes me wonder, this happens just for some transactions

Take a look at this transaction: 
[20179d0d2fba68b2ca82ab8cc5faa39ced73324af6b90b6505cca2c3d65102a6](https://testnet.blockchain.info/tx/20179d0d2fba68b2ca82ab8cc5faa39ced73324af6b90b6505cca2c3d65102a6)

As you can see inputs/outputs fee is: **0.001** BTC

In bitcoin-core gettransaction

```
bitcoin-cli gettransaction "20179d0d2fba68b2ca82ab8cc5faa39ced73324af6b90b6505cca2c3d65102a6" true
```

Returns this result:

```
Array
(
    [amount] => -105.21509845
    [fee] => 105.11519845
    [confirmations] => 78
    [blockhash] => 0000000000004caf7faef44b3cd20424b04e8044a8d323064e1fca6864b96cb9
    [blockindex] => 18
    [blocktime] => 1517902289
    [txid] => 20179d0d2fba68b2ca82ab8cc5faa39ced73324af6b90b6505cca2c3d65102a6
    [walletconflicts] => Array
        (
        )

    [time] => 1517902198
    [timereceived] => 1517902198
    [bip125-replaceable] => no
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [involvesWatchonly] => 1
                    [account] => 
                    [address] => 2N2QxAHtCMMDpxTxuNNNHvDh4burprspWPN
                    [category] => send
                    [amount] => -0.1625
                    [vout] => 0
                    [fee] => 105.11519845
                    [abandoned] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [involvesWatchonly] => 1
                    [account] => 
                    [address] => 2MtuDKij5ueE4C9D5wjA3Ft9bkjMJByxr4d
                    [category] => send
                    [amount] => -105.05259845
                    [vout] => 1
                    [fee] => 105.11519845
                    [abandoned] => 
                )

        )
```

But with this transaction everything is fine:

[20179d0d2fba68b2ca82ab8cc5faa39ced73324af6b90b6505cca2c3d65102a6](https://testnet.blockchain.info/tx/b0ad2f8047b6bfc6a0da4947ec7cda59ccf423df2d24dcbf2996042cdf45c10a)

```
bitcoin-cli gettransaction "20179d0d2fba68b2ca82ab8cc5faa39ced73324af6b90b6505cca2c3d65102a6" true
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [amount] => -1.049
    [fee] => -0.001
    [confirmations] => 136
    [blockhash] => 0000000000000fd2e83cc1a8145b055a1a33ea996f7a93578197a48848201a5b
    [blockindex] => 1
    [blocktime] => 1517898674
    [txid] => b0ad2f8047b6bfc6a0da4947ec7cda59ccf423df2d24dcbf2996042cdf45c10a
    [walletconflicts] => Array
        (
        )

    [time] => 1517898650
    [timereceived] => 1517898650
    [bip125-replaceable] => no
    [details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [involvesWatchonly] => 1
                    [account] => 
                    [address] => mxKPZ2rnev5odtFTqS273946YgQfY7H6E5
                    [category] => send
                    [amount] => -0.0001
                    [vout] => 0
                    [fee] => -0.001
                    [abandoned] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [involvesWatchonly] => 1
                    [account] => 
                    [address] => 2NG1QAAFsM71L7YwVxkjSeMbKYpW6KFURXs
                    [category] => send
                    [amount] => -1.0489
                    [vout] => 1
                    [fee] => -0.001
                    [abandoned] => 
                )

        )
```

to get the fee of that type of transactions we could do:

105.21509845 (amount) - 105.11519845(fee) = 0.001

But why bitcoin core doesn't do it and why it's only for some transactions?